# How many senders can a Chromecast connect with?

Tags: chromecast

Since I am developing a Chromecast Receiver App for music streaming service which can be connected with multiple senders (iOS, Android App).

So I was wondering about how many senders can connect with a single receiver app?

I can't find any information about it either on Chromecast Document or internet :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mostly a matter of memory/cpu (resources in general) on your cast device, there is no pre-defined limit.